# printing out value that separated with comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm start learning python. I would like to output value which is separated with a comma. I tried to pass `end=","` in `print()`. But it doesn't work. I found `join` function in the internet but which can only join an iterable.

```
#Fibonacci series
a,b = 0, 1
while b < 10:
    print(b, end=",")
    a,b = b,a+b
```

Output:

```
1,1,2,3,5,8,
```

How do I remove comma which is added in the last value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
a,b = 0, 1
op = []    # to store values of b
while b < 10:
    op.append(b)
    a,b = b,a+b
print(*op, sep=",")
```

Output:

```
1,1,2,3,5,8
```

**Edit**

`*` inside a `print` used to unwrap the iterables.
eg.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
print(*l1)
```

will give you `1 2 3` and you can decide which separator you want to use. By default it is `' '` (space). In your case you need `','`

*with dictionary*

```
d = {'a': 5, 'b': 7}
print(*d)
```

output:

```
a b  # it will return the keys.
```

Comment: could you explain `*` usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply save the output in a string and then trim the last comma when you print the output, as follows:

```
a,b = 0, 1
output = ''
while b < 10:
    output += str(b) + ','
    a,b = b,a+b

print(output[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want last , you have to go back one char and print space like below
would work. add just following print at the end will make this happen

```
print("\b ") # there is space char of \b
```

you program look like below

```
a,b = 0, 1
while b < 10:
    print(b, end=",")
    a,b = b,a+b
print("\b ")
```